# Refactoring from promise to async await and use pagination

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to re factor this code to use `async/await`

```js
fetchTopRatedMovies(pageNumber).then((newData) =>
      setApiData({
        ...newData,
        results: [...apiData.results, ...newData.results]
      })
    );
```

I;m trying to use it in a try catch block within a useEffect

This is what I have so far.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${baseURL}${option}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en&page=${pageNumber}&region=GB`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setMovieData({
          ...movieData,
          ...data,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    setLoading(true);
    fetchData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [option, pageNumber]);
```

Problem is I think is this part

```js
 const data = await response.json();
        setMovieData({
          ...movieData,
          ...data,
        });
```

As my state `const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState({ page: 0, results: [] });` 
Is not being updated with the old data only the new data that changes on pageNumber increase.

My main goal is to have a button that adds more data onto the already displayed data.

Full code so far:

```
export const Directory = () => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState('popular');
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [movieData, setMovieData] = useState({ page: 0, results: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(
          `${baseURL}${option}?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en&page=${pageNumber}&region=GB`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        setMovieData({
          ...movieData,
          ...data,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    setLoading(true);
    fetchData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [option, pageNumber]);

  const { results, page, total_pages } = movieData;

  const handleOptionChange = e => {
    setOption(e.target.value);
    setPageNumber(1);
  };
  const pageLimit = page === 0 || page < total_pages;

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={option} onChange={e => handleOptionChange(e)}>
        <option value='popular'>Popular</option>
        <option value='top_rated'>Top Rated</option>
        <option value='now_playing'>Now Playing</option>
      </select>
      <ul>
        {results &&
          results.map(movie => {
            return <li key={movie.id}>{movie.title}</li>;
          })}
      </ul>
      {results && (
        <button
          disabled={!pageLimit}
          onClick={() => setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1)}>
          More
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Currently only one page results data displays at a time. So for first render page 1. Then when I click the more button. It fetchs page 2 results. However it only displays one page at a time. I want the new results to be added to the already rendered data. So with each button press more results are displayed.

### console.log of `data = await response.json()`

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "total_results": 10000,
  "total_pages": 500,
  "results": [
    {
      "popularity": 728.376,
      "vote_count": 3070,
      "video": false,
      "poster_path": "/xBHvZcjRiWyobQ9kxBhO6B2dtRI.jpg",
      "id": 419704,
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/5BwqwxMEjeFtdknRV792Svo0K1v.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Ad Astra",
      "genre_ids": [
        18,
        878
      ],
      "title": "Ad Astra",
      "vote_average": 6,
      "overview": "The near future, a time when both hope and hardships drive humanity to look to the stars and beyond. While a mysterious phenomenon menaces to destroy life on planet Earth, astronaut Roy McBride undertakes a mission across the immensity of space and its many perils to uncover the truth about a lost expedition that decades before boldly faced emptiness and silence in search of the unknown.",
      "release_date": "2019-09-18"
    },
    {
      "popularity": 220.799,
      "id": 454626,
      "video": false,
      "vote_count": 2868,
      "vote_average": 7.5,
      "title": "Sonic the Hedgehog",
      "release_date": "2020-02-14",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Sonic the Hedgehog",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        878,
        35,
        10751
      ],
      "backdrop_path": "/stmYfCUGd8Iy6kAMBr6AmWqx8Bq.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "Based on the global blockbuster videogame franchise from Sega, Sonic the Hedgehog tells the story of the world’s speediest hedgehog as he embraces his new home on Earth. In this live-action adventure comedy, Sonic and his new best friend team up to defend the planet from the evil genius Dr. Robotnik and his plans for world domination.",
      "poster_path": "/aQvJ5WPzZgYVDrxLX4R6cLJCEaQ.jpg"
    },
    {
      "popularity": 204.235,
      "vote_count": 3202,
      "video": false,
      "poster_path": "/y95lQLnuNKdPAzw9F9Ab8kJ80c3.jpg",
      "id": 38700,
      "adult": false,
      "backdrop_path": "/upUy2QhMZEmtypPW3PdieKLAHxh.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Bad Boys for Life",
      "genre_ids": [
        28,
        80,
        53
      ],
      "title": "Bad Boys for Life",
      "vote_average": 7.2,
      "overview": "Marcus and Mike are forced to confront new threats, career changes, and midlife crises as they join the newly created elite team AMMO of the Miami police department to take down the ruthless Armando Armas, the vicious leader of a Miami drug cartel.",
      "release_date": "2020-01-17"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be awaiting the response.json() function because it returns JSON, not a Promise. `const data = await response.json();` should be `const data = response.json();`

Comment: @j-petty `response.json()` returns a promise. Its correct. @DGB Not sure what is the problem. Add expected result and current result

Comment: @Rashomon, you're right, turns out it does. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). Interesting, I've never seen an example where it's awaited like this.

Comment: @j-petty Happened to me too :)

Comment: The code seems correct, have you debugged?

Comment: The issue is that on first render. page 1 results loads. When I click on the 'more' button ONLY page 2 loads and so on. I want to add each page results to the already rendered results.

Comment: what you're looking for is called infinity scoll.

Comment: @DGB Can you please post the output of `await response.json()` ?

Comment: Ok I've edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your movieData structure is:

```
{ page: 0, results: [] }
```

When you do:

```
setMovieData({
  ...movieData,
  ...data,
})
```

It just replaces the previous data with the newer one. Because the keys of both new and old data are the same. What you need to do is something like this:

```
setMovieData({
  results: [
      ...movieData.results, ...data.results
  ],
  page: data.page
})
```

It will append new data after old data. Hope it helps.

Another mistake is with the following code:

```
const pageLimit = page === 0 || page < total_pages;
```

This needs to be managed directly with `movieData` state. Update your code as following:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={option} onChange={e => handleOptionChange(e)}>
        <option value='popular'>Popular</option>
        <option value='top_rated'>Top Rated</option>
        <option value='now_playing'>Now Playing</option>
      </select>
      <ul>
        {movieData.results &&
          movieData.results.map(movie => {
            return <li key={movie.id}>{movie.title}</li>;
          })}
      </ul>
      {movieData.results && (
        <button
          disabled={!(movieData.page === 0 || movieData.page < total_pages)}
          onClick={() => setPageNumber(pageNumber + 1)}>
          More
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: I tried this code but it disabled my button? But I now understand about my data being replaced. So thanks for that.

Comment: That's because of the rest of your code. 
`const { results, page, total_pages } = movieData;` This needs to be handled by state. Let me update my answer to fix that as well.

Comment: @DGB I've updated the code to fix that button issue.

Comment: This hasn't fixed the issue unfortunately. Strange. This works  ```fetchData(pageNumber).then((newData) =>
      setApiData({
        ...newData,
        results: [...apiData.results, ...newData.results]
      })``` But I was wanting to use async await

Comment: Just noticed. In the above code, you need to move the `fetchData` function outside `useEffect` and then in `useEffect`, you have to call `fetchData` like this: `await fetchData();`

Comment: @DGB please, do not forget to accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem.